# Persistent Loading in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

I've noticed that on the desktop version of Chrome, sites that employ Disqus will constantly load user comments and even post a "someone is typing..." message when appropriate. I was wondering if this feature is available as a setting or developer flag in the mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself! Turns out the symptom was *far* from the problem. At the time of posting this question, I was using a hosts file generated by AdAway. Before that, I was using the MoAAB hosts file. *Neither* allowed persistent loading in chrome.

I have since moved to [Dan Pollock's hosts file](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/hosts) and have been wonderfully happy. While it similarly blocks most if not all ads, it fixed problems with broken non-invasive redirects through ad networks, and, pertinent to this question, allows mobile chrome to once again persistently load data from an embedded app such as Disqus!

I hope this helps even one other person out there with a similar problem. Best of luck! :)